# Max tps support by postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.5, tps

Required TPS 200K in postgreSQL database. How much TPS can support by postgreSQL. what hardware and configuration required to achieve this TPS.

Comment: This completely depends on the hardware you use. Additionally: if you really care for performance you shouldn't use 9.5 any more. Use 12 or wait for 13

Comment: Thankyou. But do we have any hardware details that can achieve this tps